# How to use AsynsTask in JAVA (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the following code:

```
int my_couter = 0;

if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
        my_couter += 1;
}
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    my_couter += 1;
}
if (_checkPermission("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fnet.wargaming.wot.blitz%2Ffiles%2Fpacks/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata%2Fnet.wargaming.wot.blitz%2Ffiles%2Fpacks")) {
    my_couter += 1;
}
if (_checkPermission("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMTG%20MODS/document/primary%3AMTG%20MODS")) {
    my_couter += 1;
}
```

I need it to execute this in the background when a button is pressed and return the result (my_couter) to me

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _view) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

AsyncTask is deprecated now. Better you can use this.

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

           //perform background task here and finally update the UI with result this way -

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                      //Do something on UiThread

                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an inner class and extend it from `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`.
This allows you to override three main callbacks.

- `protected void onPreExecute()`
- `protected String doInBackground(String... params)`
- `protected void onPostExecute(String s)`

Now, as per your requirement, you wont be using the onPreExecute.

But, you should use `doInBackground` - this is were you will update your variable namely `my_counter`

Lastly, when the AsyncTask is completed, the `onPostExecute` is called and there you will return your variable respectively.

Do give it a try.